# Creating an array of a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am trying to make an array of structs, but I am getting the error `no matching function for call to 'Cell::Cell()'`.

`Cell` is the name of my struct. Here is some of my code:

```
struct Cell{
    int number;

    Cell(int n){
        number = n;
    }
};

class MyClass{
    public:
        int nCells;

        void inject(){
            std::cout << "Enter number:";
            string in;
            std::cin >> in;
            int amount = in.size()/3;

            Cell cells [amount]; // <-- error

            int index = 0;
            int t = in.size();
            while (t >= 3){
                cells[index] = new Cell(atoi(in.substr(t-3,3).c_str());
                t -= 3;
                index++;
            }
        }

        MyClass(int n){
            nCells = n;
        }
};
```

`Cell cells [amount];` is giving me the error. I am new to classes, but I know how to make arrays of primitive types. `int cells [amount];` would work, for instance.

But how am I supposed to make an array of type `Cell` ?

Comment: Where's default constructor in Cell? You does not have it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cell` doesnt have a default constructor (as soon as you specify another constructor the compiler will not create a default constructor anymore). However the definition `Cell cells[amount]` will automatically default initialize every element.

I think the best way in this particular situation is simply to implement a default constructor:

```
struct Cell{
    int number;

    Cell() : number(0)
    {
    }

    Cell(int n) : number(n)
    {
    }
};
```

Also notice as `amount` is not known at compile time, `Cell cells[amount]` is basically illegal. However some compilers have extensions to allow this. But its better if you heap allocate it:

```
Cell* cells = new Cell[amount];
```

Dont forget to destroy it however.

Comment: Modern C++ prefers std::shared_ptr<Cell> cells(new Cell[amount]), because then you can't forget to destroy it.

Comment: It works! I have a side question: Is there a difference between the way we wrote our constructors? You write `Name(argument): number(n) {}` , while I wrote `Name(argument) { number(n) }`

Comment: It's the same story as your question. " : number(n)" calls the constructor for number with parameter n.  { number = n; } calls the default constructor for number, and then AFTER does number= n.  In this case, no real difference, but in general it's less efficient - and if you don't have a default constructor (like you didn't) it would actually fail your way.

Comment: No,  no, no with regards to `new Cell[amount]`.  Use `std::vector<Cell> cells(amount);`.  (There's practically never a case where you'd use an array new.)

Comment: And to get the default constructor, the simplest solution is to provide a default argument for the existing construnctor: `Cell(int n = 0) ...`.

Comment: @JamesKanze in this particular case, maybe, but generally no (just imagine you have multiple constructors) and as code should have an uniform style I would always prefer to write it explicitely (especially as its not much boilerplate code). Btw, also ask yourself: What happens if I change my class?

Comment: @JamesKanze He used an array so did I

Comment: @AlanBaljeu Yes, but we should keep it as simple as possible

Comment: @Paranaix re: default arguments: when in doubt, I too prefer the separate functions.  Constructors are a special case, since they can't simply forward (pre-C++11, anyway).  And when the action of the function is to do exactly the same thing as another, except with a default argument, I'll go with default arguments even for a function.

Comment: @Paranaix His code didn't work.  Array `new` is almost always a bad solution, when we have `std::vector`.

Comment: I concur: use std::vector as James said.  Then you don't need new, delete, or shared_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how long the array is, you can use c++11 initialization. This will do :

```
int main()
{
    Cell c[3]{ Cell(1), Cell(2), Cell(3) };
}
```

By the way this

```
Cell cells [amount];
```

is using VLAs, and that is not supported by c++ (only as extension for some compilers).

In c++, much better would be to use `std::vector` :

```
#include <vector>


struct Cell{
    int number;

    Cell(int n){
        number = n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n = 5;

    std::vector< Cell > c;

    for ( int i =0; i < n; ++ i )
    {
        c.emplace_back( Cell( i ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `emplace_back` here, which is only supported by C++11, when `push_back` will generate exactly the same code.?

Comment: @JamesKanze No idea. As you said, `push_back` works fine as well :)

Answer (score 0):

By doing `Cell cells [amount];` you are calling the `Cell` constructor, but in this case you don't have a default constructor for `Cell`, so you must use pointers instead, you are using them in the `while` stuff.

Just change

```
Cell cells [amount];
```

for

```
Cell* cells [amount];
```

Comment: @JohnDibling, it does have a constructor, but not a default one...thats why it is crashing.

Comment: @JohnDibling It has a constructor, but not a *default* constructor.

Comment: Oh, it sure didn't look like it had any defined constructors at all when I viewed this question earlier.  I must have just missed it.

Comment: This is about the worst solution imaginable.  What's wrong with providing a default constructor, or using `std::vector<Cell>`?  The less you allocate dynamically, the better you'll be.